# CSS Flip animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am following the [example David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) provides to make a flip animation. Its is all working on hover, however, I want to flip the element on click as opposed to on hover.

The following code works and flips the element on hover, however, I want to use javascript/jquery to implement this. I have tried many different ways but cannot figure out how to do this.

```css
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pf4aemn7/
HTML

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", ".flip-container", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event handler on `.flip-container`, instead of [`ontouchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchstart). And of course don't forget to remove the css `:hover` selector from your styles (i.e. `.flip-container:hover .flipper`).

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I think you should rename the `.hover` class to something more appropriate like `.clicked`.